# Assigning nothing to double from reader with no data

Tags: vb.net

NOTE: This issue does not pertain exclusively to Null values, it relates more specifically to non double values and handling them through the reader convert assignment.

Looking for a way to check for blanks or non double values in this reader value before the reader throws an error on the Convert....

```
Dim Load_Pc As Double = Convert.ToDouble(reader("Load_Pc"))
```

Is there some way to assign nothing to Load_Pc if the reader is blank or not able to handle the value?

Comment: What type is `Load_Pc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "blanks", i assume that the actual type of the column is `string`.

Then you could either use `Double.TryParse` or check if it's null or empty

```
Dim ordinalIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Load_Pc")
Dim Load_Pc As Double = Double.MinValue
If Not reader.IsDbNull(ordinalIndex) Then
    Dim loadPC As String = reader.GetString(ordinalIndex)
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loadPC) Then
        Load_Pc = Double.Parse(loadPC)
    End If 
End If
```

Here the `TryParse` approach:

```
Double.TryParse(reader.GetString(ordinalIndex), Load_Pc)
```

However, if possible you should always store the correct type, never `string/varchar` for a numeric value or `DateTime`. Then it would be more efficient and less error-prone:

```
Dim Load_Pc As Double = reader.GetDouble(ordinalIndex)
```

---

If you want to use a `Nullable(Of Double)` instead:

```
Dim Load_Pc As Double? = Nothing
Dim dLoad_Pc As Double
If Double.TryParse(reader.GetString(ordinalIndex), dLoad_Pc) Then
    Load_Pc = dLoad_Pc
End If
```

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to create a nullable and just load a null to the db if the double convert fails?

Comment: Load _from_ or _to_ DB? `load a null to the db`

Comment: Intent would be to send DBNull into the DB table or Nothing, so that no value is stored in the DB Table for this field.

Comment: @htm11h: I've edited my answer to show how to use a `Double?` instead. However, it's not clear how you want to insert/update a value in the DB since a `DataReader` is normally used to read values not to write values. What are you using to insert/update fields, a `DataTable` and a `DataAdapter` or what else?

Comment: The Reader process here is handling an Excel import, I then send the values (parameterized) to a DB.

Comment: @htm11h: Then you have to use `DBNull.Value` in case the value is not parsable. Either use a boolean that you initialize from the return value of `Double.TryParse` or use a `Double?` as shown above to store it. Then you can either use the double value or `DBNull.Value` as value for the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

With a `Double`, the answer is no.

With a `Double?`, however, the answer would be yes. For more info check [**nullable types**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx).